# At what point does Byte code get generated?

Tags: .net, programming-languages

At what stage within the .NET framework does Bytecode get generated?

Am I correct with the statement that the user writes their source code in a language of their choice (maybe C#), when this source is compiled it is transformed into Byte Code? (what then uses this Byte code?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition from wikipedia:

> Bytecode is a term which has been used
>   to denote various forms of instruction
>   sets designed for efficient execution
>   by a software interpreter as well as
>   being suitable for further compilation
>   into machine code.

Althought bytecode is general term, it is more used in java world. In .net Intermediate Language (IL or MSIL) can be referenced to as bytecode. It is produced by every .net language compiler. Later it is executed by CLR (analogue of JVM in java world). Right before CLR executes code it is compiled by Just-In-Time compiler (part of CLR). It is compiled to native machine language and then executed by processor directly. (Managed binaries can be also precompiled)

Answer (score 0):

Any source code targeting .NET Framework is compiled to [MSIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) (MS Intermidiate Language) which can be interpreted and executed by CLR. MSIL code is compiled in the native code by JIT (Just-In-Time compiler) during application run.

Comment: @JHarley1:  Essentially, yes.  "Byte code" is normally used as a term for an intermediate language that isn't an actual machine language but resembles one.  Examples are MSIL, UCSD's p-system, the JVM, and more specialized languages for CLisp, Perl, and Python to compile into.

Comment: There is a difference.  Bytecode in the Java sense was originally designed to be easy to interpret. Not IL, it was designed to be just-in-time compiled to machine code.  Bytecode has ADDI (add two integers), IL only has ADD for any operand.

Answer (score 0):

Bytecode is a general term for most of the VM base languages.

There is the compiler the bytecode and the VM.

The compiler take your code and transform it into a bytecode.

Then the bytecode is interpreted by the VM.

The VM can have a special module called a Jit which transform 
the bytecode into a native assembly. This native assembly then 
doesn't need the VM anymore to get executed. But it obviously 
need the VM to get it called

The bytecode is just a intermediate language that site 
between the VM and your code source.